# Python 2.7 DistUtils Extension gcc output compiles but setup.py fails

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, gcc, distutils

I am attempting to build a python extension using distutils. When I run the setup.py build, it fails. It also appears to print out the gcc command it was running when it failed. If I copy that to the command line it passes.

setup.py output:

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'covariance' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dxdc_target_types__="gnu/targets/std.h" -Dxdc_target_name__=Linux86_64 -Dxdc_cfg__xheader__="\"/home/domain/user/Perforce/srcparts/src4300/src4384/matrix_benchmark/DSP/python/covara/package/cfg/covara_p86_64U.h\"" -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -I/home/domain/user/Perforce/tidsp/ti_rtsc/bios_6_52_00_12/packages -I/home/domain/user/Perforce/srcparts/src4300/src4384/matrix_benchmark/DSP/Program_Common/RTSC_Common -I/home/domain/user/Perforce/tidsp/ti_rtsc/lin/xdctools_3_50_03_33_core/packages -I/home/domain/user/Perforce/srcparts/src4300/src4384/matrix_benchmark/DSP/python/covara/.. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c covariancea.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/covariancea.o
In file included from covariancea.c:10:0:
/home/domain/user/Perforce/tidsp/ti_rtsc/lin/xdctools_3_50_03_33_core/packages/xdc/std.h:81:22: fatal error: "gnu/targets/std.h": No such file or directory
  #include xdc_target__
                  ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Now if I copy the gcc line from above and run it:

```
covariancea.c: In function ‘RunCovariance’:
covariancea.c:72:8: warning: variable ‘status’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    int status;
        ^
```

It seems to work, except when I go to the build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 directory and I don't see the .o file.

I'm sure there is something simple I am missing.

Thanks

Comment: In `setup.py` you may have to set a `-I` path so that `"gnu/targets/std.h"` can be found. The `gcc` command line already adds some `-I` paths, have you checked that `"gnu/targets/std.h"` is present in any of these paths?

Comment: Yes, the `-I/home/domain/user/Perforce/tidsp/ti_rtsc/bios_6_52_00_12/packages` has the `"gnu/targets/std.h"`. That is what is confusing. When I run that gcc line in the same shell where I attempted the setup.py, it seems to work. I can't figure out why it acts differently between setup.py and vanilla command line.